# cycles transparency not 100% transparent

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, transparency

I'm using cycles to render transparency around some leaves, but the actual transparency has a slight grey tint. I read some other place on google to increase the Transparency under Light Paths in the Render Panel, but it doesn't work for me.

Anyone has another suggestion?[image: notice the area around the leaves and the particle system plane]

[image]

Comment: you have to look at the node, it's not 100% white, maybe it's your problem? If so, push it 100% white

Comment: You mean the color in the transparent shader node? Yes it's 100% white

Comment: are you sure? by default it is not

Comment: Hmm i added an image of the material node. It is totally white.

Comment: maybe share one object with the problem (and pack the PNG): https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: could you check the rgb values in the transparent node color, cause i also think its because of that. On default they are at (0.8, 0.8, 0.8)

Comment: The other plausible thing would be that your alpha isnt absolute (0, 0, 0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raise TRANSMISSION and transparency samples:
[image]

Also don´t forget to check the ALPHA on Photoshop or GIMP, by placing a full black fill on your image as a lower layer. Delete (clean, CLAMP) your white alpha as white as it can get. Then, reload your image in Blender. This should cover it.

Comment: This worked, thank you!! I also discovered a very slight bleed into the alpha space from some of the many texture layers in photoshop. Good idea to go through all the layers :)